# Why am I getting 'train' and 'class' have different lengths"

Tags: r, dataframe

Why am I getting -

```
'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

In spite of having both of them with same lengths

```
y_pred=knn(train=training_set[,1:2],
       test=Test_set[,-3],
       cl=training_set[,3],
       k=5)
```

Their lengths are given below-

```
 > dim(training_set[,-3])
[1] 300   2
> dim(training_set[,3])
[1] 300   1



 > head(training_set)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     Age EstimatedSalary Purchased
   <dbl>           <dbl> <fct>    
1 -1.77           -1.47  0        
2 -1.10           -0.788 0        
3 -1.00           -0.360 0        
4 -1.00            0.382 0        
5 -0.523           2.27  1        
6 -0.236          -0.160 0   

> Test_set
# A tibble: 100 x 3
      Age EstimatedSalary Purchased
    <dbl>           <dbl> <fct>    
 1 -0.304          -1.51  0        
 2 -1.06           -0.325 0        
 3 -1.82            0.286 0        
 4 -1.25           -1.10  0        
 5 -1.15           -0.485 0        
 6  0.641          -1.32  1        
 7  0.735          -1.26  1        
 8  0.924          -1.22  1        
 9  0.829          -0.582 1        
10 -0.871          -0.774 0
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

It's because `knn` is expecting `class` to be a vector and you are giving it a data table with one column. The test `knn` is doing is whether `nrow(train) == length(cl)`. If `cl` is a data table that does not give the answer you are expecting. Compare:

```
> length(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3)))
[1] 1
> length(c(1,2,3))
[1] 3
```

If you use `cl=training_set$Purchased`, which extracts the vector from the table, that should fix it.

This is specific gotcha if you are moving from `data.frame` to `data.table` because the default `drop` behaviour is different:

```r
> dt <- data.table(a=1:3, b=4:6)
> dt[,2]
   b
1: 4
2: 5
3: 6
> df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6)
> df[,2]
[1] 4 5 6
> df[,2, drop=FALSE]
  b
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: Thanks David_O.That worked really well.But another colleague of mine tried the initial approach and it worked out too.How is there such a difference in the way R is treating the variable in such immensely different ways?

Comment: Are you both definitely using `data.table`? Unless you're using very different versions of R or libraries that seems most likely  - you're using `data.table` which doesn't drop and your colleague is using `data.frame` which does.